Is it bad to call First() multiple times on an IEnumerable<T> that is actually a List<T>?
I found this method:
public async Task SomeMethod(IEnumerable<Member> members)
{
    await DoSomething(members.First());
    await DoSomethingElse(members.First());
}

It's being called like this:
List<Member> members = GetMembers();
await SomeMethod(members);

I know this could be particularly bad if GetMembers() returned an IQueryable<Member>, but since it's just a List<Member>, is it still bad to call First() twice like that?
Is it best practice to call First() once and store the result in a variable?

The odds that you'll see any difference, in a task, are slim to none.  Well, none.  Nice thing about a variable is that the code is much easier to debug.

@HansPassant wouldn't First() have to create the state machine/whatever is involved in enumerating an IEnumerable<T>? Or is it smart enough to know it's a List<T> and it just returns the first element. Does it do return members[0] behind the scenes in First()?

@DavidKlempfner - you can check the source code here.  The current version checks if source is IList<TSource> list) and accesses the list by index.  Assigning the first to a variable rather than getting it twice still seems like best practice though.

First function in System.Linq.Enumerable
In System.Linq.Enumerable here's how First function was implemented:
public static TSource First<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    TSource? first = source.TryGetFirst(out bool found);
    if (!found)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowNoElementsException();
    }

    return first!;
}

TryGetFirst was called, let's have a look:
private static TSource? TryGetFirst<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, out bool found)
{
    if (source is null)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.source);
    }

    return
#if !OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE
        source is Iterator<TSource> iterator ? iterator.TryGetFirst(out found) :
#endif
        TryGetFirstNonIterator(source, out found);
}

Then TryGetFirstNonIterator was called, let's have a look:
private static TSource? TryGetFirstNonIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, out bool found)
{
    if (source is IList<TSource> list)
    {
        if (list.Count > 0)
        {
            found = true;
            return list[0];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (e.MoveNext())
            {
                found = true;
                return e.Current;
            }
        }
    }

    found = false;
    return default;
}

As we can see, it does return list[0] if the soruce is IList<TSource>.
Source Code
Suggestion to SomeMethod
Regardless of how First was implemented. The question you asked:

I know this could be particularly bad if GetMembers() returned an IQueryable, but since it's just a List, is it still bad to call First() twice like that? Is it best practice to call First() once and store the result in a variable?

I think overloading is all you need.
public async Task SomeMethod(Member member)
{
    await DoSomething(member);
    await DoSomethingElse(member);
}
public async Task SomeMethod(IEnumerable<Member> members)
{
    await SomeMethod(members.First());
}



Is it best practice to call First() once and store the result in a variable?

Yes, because you don't know how the method will be used. Even if it is only used with a list today, someone might do something else tomorrow. Like calling it with something like this:
public IEnumerable<Member> GetMembers(){
    var someValue = VeryExpensiveFunction();
    yield return new Member(someValue);
}

In this case every call to .First() would need to run VeryExpensiveFunction().
Storing the result in a variable is a good solution, or you could declare the method as SomeMethod(List<Member> members), or SomeMethod(IReadOnlyList<Member> members), in case you actually need to iterate it multiple times.
